# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm looking at improving the performance of some SQL, currently CTEs are being used and referenced multiple times in the script. Would I get improvements using a table variable instead? (Can't use a temporary table as the code is within functions).

Comment: See Craig Freedman's detailed explanation for SQL Server [link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/craigfr/archive/2007/10/18/ctes-common-table-expressions.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll really have to performance test - There is no Yes/No answer. As per Andy Living's post above links to, a CTE is just shorthand for a query or subquery.

If you are calling it twice or more in the same function, you might get better performance if you fill a table variable and then join to/select from that. However, as table variables take up space somewhere, and don't have indexes/statistics (With the exception of any declared primary key on the table variable) there's no way of saying which will be faster.

They both have costs and savings, and which is the best way depends on the data they pull in and what they do with it. I've been in your situation, and after testing for speed under various conditions - Some functions used CTEs, and others used table variables.

Comment: please add this  and cite sources, c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5eb6a/common-table-expression-in-sql-server   thanks

Comment: Hi I put bounty points, to account for any updates or clarifications, since this question was asked 10 years ago,

Comment: maybe someone can use this article as a base point https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5eb6a/common-table-expression-in-sql-server/

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. All he says is, "yes there are differences according to your situation" but says nothing about those differences... the whole point of the question is to illustrate scenarios that describe those differences.

Comment: @mattsmith5 - Some of that article you link is correct. The "CTE’s members cannot use the following clauses of keywords Distinct, Group By, Having, Top, Joins" is flat out incorrect though. Likely this was culled from a list of prohibitions for the recursive part of a recursive CTE but even then is not correct. Inner Joins are fine. You can use  `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE text like '%not allowed%recursive%'` to see a more complete list of those

Comment: I am not the original poster,  so I didnt accept it 10 years ago etc, but it's a good answer though

Answer (score 7):

A **CTE** is not much more than **syntactic sugar**.
It **enhances the readability** and **allows to avoid repetition**.

Just think of it as a placeholder for the actual statement specified in the `WITH()`-clause. The engine will replace any occurance of the CTE's name in your query with this statement (quite similar to a view). This is the meaning of *inline*.

**Compared to a previously filled table** (delared or created) You'll find **advantages**:

- useable in *ad-hoc*-queries (functions, views)
- no unexpected side effects (most narrow scope)

...and **disadvantages**:

- You cannot use the CTE's result in different statements
- You cannot use indexes, statistics to optimize your CTE's set (although it will implicitly use existing indexes and statistics of the targeted objects - if appropriate).

In **terms of performance** a *persisted* set (declared or created table) can be (much!) better in some cases, but it forces you into procedural code. You will have to *race your horses* to find out which is better...

**Example: Various approaches to do the same**

The following simple (rather useless) example describes a set of user tables together with their columns. I use various different approaches to tell SQL-Server what I want:

Try this with "include actual execution plan"

```
USE master; --in my case the master database has just 5 "user tables", you can use any other DB of course
GO
    
--simple join, first the small set joining to the large set
SELECT o.name AS TableName
      ,c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=o.object_id 
WHERE o.type='U';
GO

--simple join "the other way round" with the filter as part of the ON-clause
SELECT o.name AS TableName
      ,c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id=o.object_id AND o.type='U';
GO

--join from the large set with a sub-query to the small set
SELECT o.name AS TableName
      ,c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT o.* 
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.type='U' --user tables 
) o ON c.object_id=o.object_id;
GO

--join for large to small with a row-wise APPLY
SELECT o.name AS TableName
      ,c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT o.* 
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.type='U' --user tables 
    AND o.object_id=c.object_id
) o;
GO

--use a CTE to "pre-filter" the small set
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT o.* 
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.type='U' --user tables 
)
SELECT cte.name AS TableName
      ,c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN cte ON c.object_id=cte.object_id;
GO
```

Now look at the result and at the execution plans:

- All queries return the same result.
- All queries produce the same execution plan

Important hint: This might differ on your machine!

**Why is this?**

T-SQL is a **declarative language**. Your statement is a description of **WHAT** you want to retrieve. It is not your job to tell the engine **HOW** this is done.

SQL-Server's extremely smart engine will find the best way to get the set you asked for. In the case above all result descriptions point to the same goal. The engine can *deduce* this from various statements and finds the same plan for all of them.

**Well, is it just a matter of taste?**

In a way...

There are some important things to keep in mind:

- There is no reason for the engine to compute the CTE's result *before* the rest (although the statement might *look* so). Therefore it is **wrong** to describe a CTE as *something like a temp table*...
- In other words: The **visible order** of your statement does **not predict the actual order of execution**!
- The smart engine will reach its limits with complexity and nest level. Imagine various `VIEW`s, all using `CTE`s and calling each-other...
- There are cases where the engine really f**s up. I remember a case where a CTE did not much more than a `TRY_CAST`. The idea was to ensure valid values in the query below. But the engine thought "Oh, just a CAST, not expensiv!" and included the acutal CAST to the execution plan on a higher position. I remember another case where the engine performed an expensive operation against millions of rows (unnecessarily, the final result was filtered to a tiny set), just because the actual order of execution was not as expected.

**Okay... So when should I use a CTE?**

The following points are good reasons to use a CTE:

- A CTE can help you to avoid repeated sub queries.
- A CTE can be used multiple times within your statement, e.g. within a `JOIN` with a dynamic behavior depending on the actual row-count.
- You can use multiple CTEs within one statement and you can use the result of one CTE within a later CTE.
- There are recursive (or better *iterative*) CTEs.
- Sometimes I used *single-row*-CTEs to define / pre-compute *variables* later used in the query. Things you would do with declared variables in procedural T-SQL. You can use A `CROSS JOIN` to get them into your query easily.
- and also very nice: the [updatable CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562724/5089204) allows for very easy-to-read statements, same applies [for `DELETE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22762991/5089204).
  As above: Nothing one could not do without the CTE, but it is far better to read (I really like *speaking names*).

**Final hints**

Well, there are cases, where ugly code performs better :-)

It is always good to have clean and readable code. A CTE will help you with this. So give it a try. If the performance is bad, get into depth, look at the execution plans and try to find a reason where the engine might decide wrong.

In most cases it is a bad idea trying to outsmart the engine with hints such as `FORCE ORDER` (but in can help)

**UPDATE**

I was asked to point to advantages and disadvantages specifically:

Uhm, *technically* there are **no real advantages or disadvantages**. Disregarding *recursive CTEs* there's nothing one couldn't solve without a CTE.

*Advantages*
The main *advantage* is **readability and maintainabilty**.
Sometimes a CTE can save hundreds of lines of code. Instead of a repeating a huge sub-query one can use just a name as a *variable*. Corrections to the sub-query can be solved just in one place.
The CTE can serve in ad-hoc queries and make your life easier.

*Disadvantages*
One *possible disadvantage* is that it's very easy, even for experienced developers, to mistake a CTE as a temp table, assume that the visible order of steps will be the same as the acutal order of execution and stumble into **unexpected results or even errors**.
And - of course :-) - the strange `wrong syntax` error you'll see when you write a CTE after another statement without a separating `;`. That's why many people tend to use `;WITH`.

Comment: thanks! what are the disadvantages of CTEs btw?

Comment: @mattsmith5, hi, I've added some lines as an UPDATE-section... (+ tiny enhancements)

Comment: thanks, what do you think of the disadvantages in this article? are they true or not?  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5eb6a/common-table-expression-in-sql-server/

Comment: @mattsmith5, I would not call a "limitation" *disadvantage*... Compared to what? Yes, CTEs are limited in some ways, but they do what they are designed for. One "advantage" I did not state above (will do so later) are *updateable CTEs*. They provide a great way to articulate complex updates. But again: Nothing more than syntactic sugar. The sole "advantage" is readability...

Comment: yeah, i was referring to this one "CTE’s members cannot use the following clauses of keywords Distinct, Group By, Having, Top, Joins limiting by this type of the queries that can be created and reducing their complexity."

Comment: @mattsmith5, this is plain wrong. Might be that this was correct in earlier versions (but the article is *updated 2019*). Might be that the author mistook limitations in recursive CTEs as valid for all CTEs. No, you can use all of these keywords and  structures within a CTE. As in a VIEW you need to define `TOP` in order to use `ORDER BY`. You cannot write a CTE *within* a CTE (although you can stack them). And - for some people quite annoying: A CTE cannot be placed behind another statement without a `;` That's why we often find `;WITH`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not.  CTE's are especially good at querying data for tree structures.

Comment: Hi I put bounty points, to account for any updates or clarifications, since this question was asked 10 years ago,

Comment: maybe someone can use this article as a base point https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5eb6a/common-table-expression-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

The information and quotes are from the following article on mssqltips.com "Choose Between SQL Server Subquery T-SQL Code" by Eric Blinn. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6618/sql-server-query-performance-cte-view-subquery-temp-table-table-variable/

### SQL Server 2019 CTEs, subqueries, and views

> The SQL Server [2019] engine optimizes every query that is given to it.  When
> it encounters a CTE, traditional subquery, or view, it sees them all
> the same way and optimizes them the same way.  This involves looking
> at the underlying tables, considering their statistics, and choosing
> the best way to proceed.  In most cases they will return the same plan
> and therefore **perform exactly the same**.

#### TempDB table

> For the query that inserted rows into the temporary table, the
> optimizer looked at the table statistics and chose the best way
> forward.  It actually made new table statistics for the temporary
> table and then used them to run the second.  This **brings about very
> similar performance**.

#### Table variable

The table variable **has poor performance** in the example given in the article **due to lack of table statistics**.

> ...the table variable does not have any table statistics generated for
> it like the TempDB table did.  This means the optimizer has to make a
> wild guess as to how to proceed.  In this example it made a very, very
> poor decision.
>
> This is not to write off table variables.  They surely have their
> place as will be discussed later in the tip.

#### Temp table vs Table variable

> A temporary table will be stored on disk and have statistics
> calculated on it and a table variable will not.  Because of this
> difference temporary tables are best when the expected row count
> is >100 and the table variable for smaller expected row counts where the lack of statistics will be less likely to lead to a bad query plan.

Comment: @mattsmith5 An entry for SQL Server 2019 in response to your request for updated information

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages of CTE**

CTE can be termed as 'Temporary View' used as a good alternative for a View in some cases.
The main advantage over a view is usage of memory. As CTE's scope is limited only to its batch, the memory allocated for it is flushed as soon as its batch is crossed. But once a view is created, it is stored until user drops it. If the view is not used after creation then it's a mere waste of memory.
CPU cost for CTE execution is lesser when compared to that of View.
Like View, CTE doesn't store any metadata of its definition and provides better readability.
A CTE can be referred for multiple times in a query.
As the scope is limited to the batch, multiple CTEs can have the same name which a view cannot have.
It can be made recursive.

**Disadvantages of CTE**

Though using CTE is advantageous, it does have some limitations to be kept in mind,
We knew that it is a substitute for a view but a CTE cannot be nested while Views can be nested.
View once declared can be used for any number of times but CTE cannot be used. It should be declared every time you want to use it. For this scenario, CTE is not recommended to use as it is a tiring job for user to declare the batches again and again.
Between the anchor members there should be operators like UNION, UNION ALL or EXCEPT etc.
In Recursive CTEs, you can define many Anchor Members and Recursive Members but all the Anchor Members must be defined before the first Recursive Member. You cannot define an Anchor Member between two Recursive Member.
The number of columns, the data types used in Anchor and Recursive Members should be same.
In Recursive Member, aggregate functions like TOP, operator like DISTINCT, clause like HAVING and GROUP BY, Sub-queries, joins like Left Outer or Right Outer or Full Outer are not allowed. Regarding Joins, only Inner Join is allowed in Recursive Member.
Recursion Limit is 32767, crossing which results in the crash of server due to infinite loop.

Comment: Hi I put bounty points, to account for any updates or clarifications, since this question was asked 10 years ago,

Comment: maybe someone can use this article as a base point https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5eb6a/common-table-expression-in-sql-server/

Comment: neither CTEs or views are allocated any dedicated memory. Both of them are basically macros that get inlined into the queries that reference them.