# Why is CTE better than cursor/derived table/ subqueries/ temp table etc.?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

How and why CTE gives a better performance as compared to derived table/ subqueries/ temp table etc. approaches?

Any temporary calculations happens in the temporary database. So if we have a cursor approach, it also creates temporary table/work table in  the temporary database and once the operation is over, that work table is destroyed. My understanding of CTE is that, it also does the same(or does it creates temporary result in memory?  and hence the performance improvement) Then why is it better than the above approaches like cursor/derived table/ subqueries/ temp table etc.?

Comment: specific example? that is a rather sweeping statement that is untrue.

Comment: In general i am looking for the answer... nothing specific...

Comment: There is nothing magic about CTES that make them faster or slower than the equivalent query with subquery. There are use cases that are only possible efficiently with CTES such as recursion, but its severe edge case.

Comment: The main reason is this: cursors are a **procedural** construct - you create it, you step through it one by one. This is fine for general-purpose programming - but it's totally against the **set-based** thinking and working of SQL Server. Cursors are memory and performance hogs (in most cases), so be very very careful where and when you use them. 90% or more of the time you **don't really need** a cursor - you could do it just as fine (or much better!) with a set-based approach

Comment: @marc_s: of course, under the covers, the set based approach uses loops to process resultsets, BUT the big difference is these are SQL Server's internal, fast loops (Please don't let anyone take that to mean I'm advocating using cursors. Don't!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A (non-recursive) CTE does not use cursors. It is a set based approach. That's the big difference compared to using cursors. But then that's true of not using cursors in general.

Cursors should be avoided where absolutely possible (as I'm sure we are all aware).

A CTE is not necessarily better than using a derived table, but does lead to more understandable TSQL code. A CTE is really just shorthand for a query or subquery; something akin to a temporary view.

The situation where CTE's might not be the best approach, is when the query plan optimiser gets inaccurate row estimates for the CTE.

Related question: [What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a CTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-using-a-cte)

Comment: +1 Cursors are the devil's work - stay away from them as much as you can! Especially in triggers ... (I have such a devilish database to deal with right now....)

Comment: yes, inside a trigger - and inside that cursor, another table is updated and another trigger fires.... with another cursor inside..... this database should really be copied to DEV:NULL for good....

Comment: If the ACM or anyone ever needs an example of a truly horrific database doing all things that are forbidden and frowned upon - got a great example here :-)

Comment: And then people asked "why is it slow?" :p. I went from a cursor approach to 8 layers of CTE's on top of eachother (the final UPDATE statement being layer 9) and improved a 6 hours batch to 4 minutes !!!

Comment: @Vincent - good grief - how readable/supportable is 9 layers of CTE's???  Unless you documented what the responsibilities are for each layer, a new person trying to make a change is at high risk of failure - its like trying to comprehend the 5th dimension...  I applaud your speed improvement, but wow...

Comment: @barrypicker, Readability was alright (it was always going to be complex). The layers were mostly necessary so you could define a value x as being column1 * column2 (actually a funky case-statement) and then, in layer2 you can use x in another calculation without doubling up (and breaking the DRY principle).