# Adding values to an existing table by using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

By running this code its working, but when I add more values to the table it's not working anymore. I appreciate any help, thank you.

This code works perfectly:

```
declare @id int
declare @empid int
set @id = 0
declare @schedindate datetime
declare @ss nvarchar(100)
declare @indice nvarchar(2)
declare @FromDate datetime
declare @ToDate datetime
declare @TimeInR datetime
declare @TimeOutR datetime
declare @departmentID int 
declare @PositionID int
declare @BranchID int
declare @SupervisorID int
declare @GradeID int
declare @Custom1ID int
declare @Custom2ID int
declare @PayClassID int
declare @EmploymentType int
set @FromDate = '2009-01-14'
set @ToDate = '2010-01-30'
delete from table1
declare cc cursor for select distinct empid from ta_timecard where schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
open cc
fetch next from cc into @empid
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    set @id = @id + 1
    insert into table1 (ID, EmpID) values (@id, @empid)

    declare cc2 cursor for select distinct departmentid from ta_timecard where empid = @empid and schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
    open cc2
    fetch next from cc2 into @departmentID

    while (@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin
        set @indice = cast(datediff(day, @fromdate, @schedindate) as nvarchar(4))
        set @ss = 'update table1 set departmetid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @departmentID)
            + ' where empid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @empid)

        execute sp_executesql @ss
        fetch next from cc2 into @departmentID
    end
    close cc2
    deallocate cc2
fetch next from cc into @empid
end
close cc
Deallocate cc
GO
```

[image]

But when I add more values to the table I got the first row only affected

[image]

```
declare @id int
declare @empid int
set @id = 0
declare @schedindate datetime
declare @ss nvarchar(100)
declare @indice nvarchar(2)
declare @FromDate datetime
declare @ToDate datetime
declare @TimeInR datetime
declare @TimeOutR datetime
declare @departmentID int 
declare @PositionID int
declare @BranchID int
declare @SupervisorID int
declare @GradeID int
declare @Custom1ID int
declare @Custom2ID int
declare @PayClassID int
declare @EmploymentType int
set @FromDate = '2009-01-14'
set @ToDate = '2010-01-30'
delete from table1
declare cc cursor for select distinct empid from ta_timecard where schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
open cc
fetch next from cc into @empid
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    set @id = @id + 1
    insert into table1 (ID, EmpID) values (@id, @empid)

    declare cc2 cursor for select distinct departmentid, branchid from ta_timecard where empid = @empid --and schedindate between @FromDate and @ToDate
    open cc2
    fetch next from cc2 into @departmentID, @BranchID--,@PositionID

    while (@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin
        set @indice = cast(datediff(day, @fromdate, @schedindate) as nvarchar(4))
        set @ss = 'update table1 set departmetid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @departmentID) 
            +', branchid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @BranchID) 
            --+ ', positionid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @PositionID)
            + ' where empid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @empid)
print(@ss)
        execute sp_executesql @ss
        fetch next from cc2 into @departmentID, @BranchID--, @PositionID
    end
    close cc2
    deallocate cc2
fetch next from cc into @empid
end
close cc
Deallocate cc
GO
```

**Edited:**
this is the table ta_TimeCard

[image]

Comment: 1) Try not to use dynamic SQL when you can do without it; you can do without it in this case.
2) Cursors are evil.  Cursors in cursors are evil squared.
3) Learn about CTEs; they are your friends.  
3.1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824669/why-is-cte-better-than-cursor-derived-table-subqueries-temp-table-etc
3.2) http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/03/updates-with-cte.html

Comment: what does `select distinct departmentid, branchid from ta_timecard where empid = @empid` return on the second query for the second cursor?

Comment: it should return a list of int, sorry I don't know if I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Could you show the data contained in ta_timecard table, please.

Comment: I added the table ta_TimeCard in my question if you download the picture you can see it well, thank you for trying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need check @BranchID on NULL values

```
+ ISNULL(', branchid = ' + convert(nvarchar(4), @BranchID), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your query from

```
  set @ss = 'update table1 set departmetid = '
```

to

```
set @ss = 'update table1 set departmentid = '
```

the n might affect your result

Comment: when i created the table i wrote it without the 'n' that why i kept it like this

Comment: but i test your departmentid and branchid for me able to insert into table1, maybe is your datatype is not meet the requirement.