# SQL (SQL Server 2008) hierarchical query and subtree query for specific results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have a question on writing a query for a subtree of results returned from a hierarchical query.

Essentially I have to pull data from a table that has organizations and sub organizations.  The orgs are hierarchical and use a numerical sequence as an identifier.  A name can be assigned to several organizations.  I already have the segment for this criteria written and working (it is below).

Now, however, I have to return results of the subtree (this segment is what is to be written now) for a forthcoming web page.  It will return results for a search function where the user enters a name and can see all of the org codes that the name is associated with.  I am at a loss as to how to do this with the hierarchical query and any assistance would be most appreciated.

Here is the working code for the hierarchical query:

```
WITH OrgCode_hierarchy (ParentOrgCodeID, OrgCodeID, OrgCode, OrgName, OrgCodeSortOrder, LEVEL) AS
(

      SELECT o_base.ParentOrgCodeID, o_base.OrgCodeID, o_base.OrgCode, o_base.OrgName, cast('::' + o_base.OrgCode  + '::' AS VARCHAR (200)) AS OrgCodeSortOrder, 0 AS LEVEL
      FROM L_OrgCode o_base
      WHERE o_base.OrgCode is not null


      UNION all

      SELECT o_child.ParentOrgCodeID, o_child.OrgCodeID, o_child.OrgCode, o_child.OrgName,  cast (ho.OrgCodeSortOrder + CASE WHEN left(o_child.OrgCode, 2) = '::' THEN '::' ELSE '' END  + o_child.OrgCode + '::' AS VARCHAR (200)) AS OrgCodeSortOrder, LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL
      FROM L_OrgCode o_child
      inner join OrgCode_hierarchy ho on o_child.ParentOrgCodeID = ho.OrgCodeID
)     

SELECT DISTINCT ParentOrgCodeID, OrgCodeID, OrgCode, OrgName, OrgCodeSortOrder, LEVEL
FROM OrgCode_hierarchy 
ORDER BY 1
```

And here is a sample of the returned results from that query:

[image: Hierarchical query results sample]

Thanks again!

Comment: "see all of the org codes that the name is associated with". Associated how? The node where the name shows up only, or also all subtrees of that node?

Comment: I think the "Orgcode" describes the hierarchical info?

Comment: For hierarchical details, building a string with hierarchical details (Like Orgcode-exactly) and use Like operator with % at end of the string to get all the child records for the given account or organization is my own logic that I have created for replacing recursive CTE. My question is, how did you know the same logic exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just add the Id of the user in the CTE, and just add a where clause in the final query? i.e :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ParentOrgCodeID, OrgCodeID, OrgCode, OrgName, OrgCodeSortOrder, LEVEL
FROM OrgCode_hierarchy 
**where [UserId] = '[UserId]'**
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer.  To be honest I'm not entirely certain.  My direction was to come up with the hierarchical query.  Then once I completed that, I was shown another query that uses a cursor where there was a similar function.

The cursor segment was in the hierarchical segement and returnes a list of items a user had access to.  My direction was "take this and use it as a model for the hierarchical search for the orgs" at which point I got very lost.

Comment: @Joachim;

AH, sorry for the lack of clarity.  I need the name node and all of the orgs that are against that name.

@Sivakumar;

Yes, the Orgcode is that hierarchical info.

Comment: You still need the CTE to extract the hierarchy - it is just the filter in the result set which is missing. I would definitely prefer a CTE, from a cursor. Some more tips why you should go for CTE : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824669/why-is-cte-better-than-cursor-derived-table-subqueries-temp-table-etc

Comment: Thank you for the advice and research source.  I will look into that resource.  I will post anything I find here.

Please excuse my many questions in this thread, SQL is quite new to me.

Comment: that link you provided was very educational!  Thank you much.  I am going to try the filter you suggested, however it is going to take a little tweaking.  For some reason, all of the UserIDs in my lookuptable (which is what the query runs on) are returning Null.  I'll post a final solution if I get it.

Comment: Update: The issue I am struggling with now is that while there is a UserId field, the lookup table has the entries set to NULL.  Unfortunately, I do not have permission to alter this table yet.  I'm working on getting that modified.  In the meantime, I continue to try to work the solution.

Comment: Glad that the post helped you :) If you do not have permission to alter the physical table, you can insert the results into a temporary table, and alter the temporary table. That however would be a workaround.

Comment: Update: I have changed the CTE in accordance with a requirement change.  They now want to be able to type in all or part of an OrgCode and get all the codes equal to and below that one, with the name(s) assigned to them.  In the end I will create a stored procedure to operate behind a webform for this, but right now I'm just trying to get the query to work.

For this new requirement the qeury is working, however I now need to filter the results more cleanly.  Would this have to be done via the webform, or is it possible to do it in the query itself (a followup comment will illustrate this more

Comment: The updated CTE w/test data:

`SELECT DISTINCT ParentOrgCodeID, OrgCodeID, OrgCode, OrgName, OrgCodeSortOrder, LEVEL
FROM OrgCode_hierarchy
WHERE OrgCode LIKE '2.2.1%' 
ORDER BY OrgCode, 1`

This now returns a dataset with the results I need but for multiple names for the same Org Code I get a row for each. I'm trying to get the multiple names to appear against an Org Code one time.

I imagine that I would have to create another column on the fly and place the concatenated name values there, but truly am not clear on how to proceed.

Thank you for the continued help!

Comment: Exactly. That should be suitable for your requirements. I am glad I helped.

Answer (score -1):

A common table expression (CTE) provides the significant advantage of being able to reference itself, thereby creating a recursive CTE. A recursive CTE is one in which an initial CTE is repeatedly executed to return subsets of data until the complete result set is obtained.

For More Detail:
http://rajeshprajapati.blogspot.in/2012/04/recursive-query-for-parent-id.html

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**