# Update records in table from CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the following CTE that will give me the DocTotal for the entire invoice.

```
 ;WITH CTE_DocTotal
 AS
 (
   SELECT SUM(Sale + VAT) AS DocTotal
   FROM PEDI_InvoiceDetail
   GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
 )

UPDATE PEDI_InvoiceDetail
SET DocTotal = CTE_DocTotal.DocTotal
```

Now with this result I want to enter into the column the DocTotal value inside PEDI_InvoiceDetail.

I know is not going to work and I know I am missing something, what is it?

Comment: I have chosen the CTE option for better performance.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Updates you make to the CTE will be cascaded to the source table.

I have had to guess at your schema slightly, but something like this should work.

```
;WITH T AS
(   SELECT  InvoiceNumber, 
            DocTotal, 
            SUM(Sale + VAT) OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceNumber) AS NewDocTotal
    FROM    PEDI_InvoiceDetail
)
UPDATE  T
SET     DocTotal = NewDocTotal
```

Comment: Is CTE UPDATE atomic , if run concurent queries will the same records updated twice ?

Comment: A CTE update is no different at all from a normal update. It is atomic and will take the same table/row locks. It is nothing more than syntactic sugar

Comment: @GarethD - MERGE statements are not atomic, and the MSFT Docs page for CTE mentions nothing about atomicity - do you have any evidence to back that statement?

Comment: @StingyJack This question has nothing to do with `MERGE` so not sure what the relevance of `MERGE` not being atomic is. As for the CTE I can't find an exact reference that states they are atomic, but I also can't find this in the docs for `UPDATE`. a
As stated above, a CTE is syntactic sugar and the compiler will rewrite as a normal update, so if a normal update is atomic, as is an Update that references a CTE. The best I can do in terms of evidence is show you an example of both ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJGKQk6I)) to demonstrate that they have the exact same execution plan.

Comment: I referred to MERGE because many people assume that MERGE statements are atomic yet they are not. In the example where a CTE is simple, it probably always results in just syntactic sugar for an UPDATE. I dont know if the same can be said when CTEs are nested or use data from other tables, and its not stated in the documentation that it is.

Comment: A CTE is no different from a query written with a subquery, the CTE is purely there for aesthetic purposes, and is compiled away. So if you have concerns about an update not being atomic then the CTE should not be a relevant factor, e.g. You're concern could similarly be "If an update has nested subqueries or uses data from other tables, then it might not be atomic because it is not stated in the documentation that it would be". If you are happy that an update without a CTE is atomic, then by proxy you should be happy that an update with a CTE is atomic.

Comment: If your concern is specifically about race conditions and concurrency, then a simple update is susceptible to these without elevating locking, so a CTE isn't a contributing factor. `MERGE` is no different in this aspect, with elevated locks you can almost completely remove the risk of a race condition. In both cases the presence of a CTE, or lack of, will not be a contributing factor to the risk of concurrency issues.

Comment: @GarethD I can say for sure that Update with CTE is not atomic. I came here looking for a solution for a deadlock situation I constantly running into calling a very similar Update from multiple clients in parallel.

Comment: @IamanSwtrse I think perhaps atomicity doesn't guarantee what you expect. It just means the statement is entirely committed or entirely rolled back. Your deadlock issues are related to the isolation levels of the query.  The fact that you are seeing deadlocks (with or without CTE) and the statement is failing and entirely rolled back is more of a sign the statement is atomic rather than a sign it is not..

Comment: @GarethD You are wrong. An atomic statement may be able to generate a deadlock but it is very very unlikely (if there are no other statements running). The reason is that UPDATE may lead to a deadlock situation but since the statements use the same execution plan they scan the tables in the same order so it will lead to blocking instead of deadlocks. In my case i run into deadlocks nearly instantly and also tried UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK hints. My solution at the moment that is working is to use the UPDLOCK and READPAST hint. However I want to find the reason to avoid that in the future.

Comment: @IamanSwtrse Again, you are misunderstanding what atomicity means - Are you experiencing a situation where your update only updates some of the rows it should, leaving others not updated? Or does it only even update everything, or update nothing. If it is the latter then your statement is atomic. The fact that you have said using locking hints is your solution simply confirms what I said about your issue being with isolation levels. Believe me or not, I won't lose any sleep over it, but your issue is nothing to do with a CTE, or the statement not being atomic.

Answer (score 55):

```
WITH CTE_DocTotal (DocTotal, InvoiceNumber)
AS
(
    SELECT  InvoiceNumber,
            SUM(Sale + VAT) AS DocTotal
    FROM    PEDI_InvoiceDetail
    GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
)    
UPDATE PEDI_InvoiceDetail
SET PEDI_InvoiceDetail.DocTotal = CTE_DocTotal.DocTotal
FROM CTE_DocTotal
INNER JOIN PEDI_InvoiceDetail ON ...
```

Answer (score 32):

You don't need a CTE for this

```
UPDATE PEDI_InvoiceDetail
SET
    DocTotal = v.DocTotal
FROM
     PEDI_InvoiceDetail
inner join 
(
   SELECT InvoiceNumber, SUM(Sale + VAT) AS DocTotal
   FROM PEDI_InvoiceDetail
   GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
) v
   ON PEDI_InvoiceDetail.InvoiceNumber = v.InvoiceNumber
```

Comment: But what is the correct way to do this? Which is faster? Which is more readable?

Comment: @Zack "Correctness" and "readability" in SQL are to some extent subjective and a matter of taste. However, some historic versions of SQL server don't contain the CTE feature.

Comment: SQLite3 3.8.11.1 complains: Error: near "FROM": syntax error

Comment: @HolgerJakobs This question is about SQL Server. SQLite will have its own syntax

Comment: The question is about how to update records from CTE, not about alternate approaches.  There are several reasons the OP may have wanted to use a CTE which aren't revealed in the question.

Comment: @DerekGreer The OP says "I want to enter into the column the DocTotal value inside PEDI_InvoiceDetail." He doesn't say he needs or wants to necessarily use a CTE.

Comment: Correct, except for the fact that he summarizes his question in the title: "Update records in table from CTE".  As evidence I'm reading the OP's desire for an answer that involves a CTE, I submit as evidence that he accepted an answer providing a solution using a CTE and that he stated in a follow up comment that he chose a CTE for performance.

Comment: Actually updating the same table based on a query *of that table* will break concurrency and force the query to run twice. Once, correctly, and finally with the final value which is the last record of the subquery. Try it

Answer (score 1):

Try the  following query:

```
;WITH CTE_DocTotal
 AS
 (
   SELECT SUM(Sale + VAT) AS DocTotal_1
   FROM PEDI_InvoiceDetail
   GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
 )

UPDATE CTE_DocTotal
SET DocTotal = CTE_DocTotal.DocTotal_1
```

Comment: I believe this will give "Invalid column name DocTotal" and you thus you need to add `DocTotal` to the SELECT in the CTE perhaps?