# How can I improve this query for performance, provide status, and run as SQL job?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, in two different databases. I am using one of the tables to update values in the other database table.

There are over 200,000 rows to iterate through, and it is taking several hours to run, on an Amazon c3.xlarge instance.

Below is the query I am running, and I am wondering three things:

1. Can this query be optimized to perform faster?
2. I would like to add a count to get the number of actual records
   updated.How?
3. How can I turn this into a SQL job?

> ```
> DECLARE @id VARCHAR(12) -- unique id
> DECLARE @currentval VARCHAR(64) -- current value
> DECLARE @newval VARCHAR(64) -- updated value
>
> DECLARE db_cursor1 CURSOR FOR  
> SELECT b.[id], a.status, b.[New Status]  
> FROM db1.dbo.['account'] as b inner join db2.dbo.accounttemp as a on a.ACCOUNTID = b.[ID]
>
> OPEN db_cursor1   
> FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1
> INTO @id,
> @currentval,
> @newval
>
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
> BEGIN   
> UPDATE db2.dbo.accounttemp 
> SET status = @newval
> WHERE ACCOUNTID = @id
> AND STATUS = @currentval
>
> FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1
> INTO @id,
> @currentval,
> @newval   
> END   
>
> CLOSE db_cursor1   
> DEALLOCATE db_cursor1
> ```

Comment: Cursors are slow, this is easy to update with `UPDATE aliasName FROM ...`, I suggest you try making this replacement, and check your performance afterwards to see if it's satisfactory.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a cursor here. This seems simple enough to be done with a single set-based UPDATE...

Comment: Probably you may use Common Table Expressions
Have a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By reviewing the procedure, you will see that you can completely remove the cursor using the following SQL

   UPDATE db2.dbo.accounttemp
   SET status = a.Status
   FROM db2.dbo.accounttemp at
   INNER JOIN db1.dbo.['account'] AS a ON a.Id = at.[ACCOUNTID]
   WHERE a.Status = at.Status
2. call the following line to return the rows affected by the update

   ```
   RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
   ```
3. You can create an SQL maintenance plan to run this on scheduled basis

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is obvious by the nature of my question that I am new to cursors and running more advanced SQL statements. I was using a cursor, because I thought that was the only way I can iterate through each of the records to perform an update. Can you provide a complete example of the SQL I need to run, and explain how your SQL iterates through each record? Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1770228 What makes you say you need to iterate?

Comment: Because there are 200,000 unique records in the source table that contain new values that need to be updated in the destination table. If I dont iterate through the records, how does it perform an update for each new value/unique record?

Comment: In the above example where is the @currentval variable being set? When I try to run that sql statement above it errors out: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
Must declare the scalar variable "@currentval".

Comment: In my original example @currentval was being declared and set using a cursor? So the above example seems incomplete?

Comment: According to my understaning, for each account in the account table, you want to update the new status into  status field of accounttemp table. Since you are updating the whole table(based on the where clause), i dont see any necessity of loop. or may be I mis understood your code completely. (I edited the query a bit)

Comment: This query worked, thank you! I guess I didnt need to iterate as SQL is smarter than I am! I come more from a programming background, and am use to having to iterate through things to make updates. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1770228 You should look up the difference between a *declarative* programming language and a *procedural* programming language. That will help you to understand the differences between SQL and say Python, C, or JavaScript.