# UPDATE and SELECT after CTE - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a view that incorporates a CTE. My overall goal is to select the max date from the CTE, but if that date is NULL, then convert it to DATETIME and finally select the date that is greater than then max date by comparing the date to the CTE.

I know this sounds confusing, but below is my query (hopefully its clearer):

```
;WITH cte (MaxDate) AS (
                    SELECT MAX(date) AS MaxDate
                        FROM ServerA.tableNameA
                    )

UPDATE cte
SET MaxDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)
WHERE MaxDate IS NULL 

SELECT top 1000 c1, c2,..etc
    FROM ServerB.tableNameA
    WHERE date > (SELECT MaxDate    
                        FROM cte)
```

I think  read online that I am not allowed to have an UPDATE and SELECT after a CTE, so how can I go about this?

Comment: You can update from a CTE. But here not update a table field, you change the `Max()` value, and you cant have update and select after the cte, only one

Comment: You also can't UPDATE inside a view.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Yes, you can update a cte and reflect on the table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte

Comment: if the Max(Date) is null then none of the fields have a Date so what in the world would your query return?

Comment: @JamieD77 ServerA.tableNameA <> ServerB.tableNameA

Comment: I also said a VIEW, not a CTE.  The  OP states "I am trying to create a view that incorporates a CTE..."  You can UPDATE a CTE, but not inside a VIEW.

Comment: `coalesce(MAX(date), CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)) as maxDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just improve your cte to return the right value and you wont need the update

```
;WITH cte (MaxDate) AS (
     SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN MAX(date) IS NULL THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)
                 ELSE MAX(date)
            END AS MaxDate
     FROM ServerA.tableNameA
)
SELECT top 1000 c1, c2,..etc
FROM ServerB.tableNameA
WHERE date > (SELECT MaxDate    
              FROM cte)
```