# Run the Update Statement from another Select in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an update query that will update my table values based on pallet number match.

```
SELECT [pallet] [quantity] 
FROM dba.Inventory
```

This will returns 2 columns, one with pallet and the other with count.

I need to put this in a update statement that will match each pallet between here and table TABLE1 and update the counts in TABLE1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update records in table from CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Common Table Expression.

Syntax goes like

```
with CTE_Values()
AS
( --- Your Statement---)
Update T
Set Col = C.col
From Table T Join CTE_Values C
On .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that one easy solution (without evaluating the `SELECT` itself that looks quite convoluted) is to put the whole `SELECT` into a `CTE` and use it as source for your update. Something like this:

```
;WITH SrcCte AS (
    SELECT pallet, SUM(total) as quantity
    FROM ( 

    SELECT r1.pallet, total 
    FROM
    (SELECT plet_nbr, COUNT(serl_nbr) as total FROM Inventory group by plet_nbr  )c1
    right join
    (select pallet from dbo.RFS where status NOT LIKE 'Not Available')r1
    on  r1.pallet = c1.plet_nbr 

    UNION all

    Select r2.pallet, sum(iloc_qty) as total
    FROM
    (SELECT plet_nbr, iloc_qty FROM Inventory WHERE([matl_nbr] Like '#%')) c2
    right join
    (select pallet from dbo.RFS where status NOT LIKE 'Not Available') r2
    on  r2.pallet = c2.plet_nbr 
    where iloc_qty is not null
    GROUP BY r2.pallet 
    )
    AS final

    GROUP BY pallet
)
UPDATE Dest
SET Dest.Cnt = Src.Quantity             
FROM Table1 AS Dest
    JOIN SrcCte AS Src ON Src.pallet = Dest.pallet
```