# Update statement SQL with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a common table expression that I am using trying to use as an update statement.   The only reason for the CTE is so I can use a where clause to filter by CredCount.  I would like to use that where clause to update only records that match in this case CredCount of 2.  However, I am having trouble with the update part of the query.

| Members_id | Credentials | CredCount | members_amountdue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CMA, CPR | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | CMA, CPR | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | CMA, CPR | 2 | 0 |

Here is the query for that

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT members_id,   members_amountdue,  [Credentials], LEN([Credentials]) - LEN(REPLACE([Credentials], ',', '')) + 1 AS CredCount
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT  mem1.members_id, mem1.members_amountdue, 
            STUFF(
                (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + credentials_code
                FROM members AS mem JOIN
                members_credentials  AS mc ON mc.members_id = mem.members_id JOIN
                credentials AS c ON c.credentials_id = mc.credentials_id
                WHERE mem.[members_id] = mem1.[members_id]              
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS [Credentials]
        FROM members AS mem1 JOIN
        members_status as ms on ms.members_status_id = mem1.members_status_id   
    ) AS derived),
CTE2 AS ( SELECT members_id
            FROM members)
SELECT  CTE.members_id, CTE.Credentials, CTE.CredCount, (CTE.members_amountdue + 25) as NewPriceTotal
FROM CTE JOIN
CTE2 ON CTE.members_id = CTE2.members_id
WHERE CTE.CredCount = 2
```

With the update statement I was looking at an example provided here at [Update records in table from CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte?noredirect=1&lq=1) so I added the update statement to the bottom of the query

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT members_id,   members_amountdue,  [Credentials], LEN([Credentials]) - LEN(REPLACE([Credentials], ',', '')) + 1 AS CredCount
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT  mem1.members_id, mem1.members_amountdue, 
            STUFF(
                (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + credentials_code
                FROM members AS mem JOIN
                members_credentials  AS mc ON mc.members_id = mem.members_id JOIN
                credentials AS c ON c.credentials_id = mc.credentials_id
                WHERE mem.[members_id] = mem1.[members_id]              
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS [Credentials]
        FROM members AS mem1 JOIN
        members_status as ms on ms.members_status_id = mem1.members_status_id   
    ) AS derived),
CTE2 AS ( SELECT members_id
            FROM members)
SELECT  CTE.members_id, CTE.Credentials, CTE.CredCount, (CTE.members_amountdue + 25) as NewPriceTotal
FROM CTE JOIN
CTE2 ON CTE.members_id = CTE2.members_id
WHERE CTE.CredCount = 2
UPDATE members
set members_amountdue = NewPriceTotal
```

When I add the update statement I get an error for invalid column name for 'NewPriceTotal'.  I know I need the column to match in order for the update to work but I'm not sure why it's invalid.

| Members_id | Credentials | CredCount | NewPriceTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CMA, CPR | 2 | 25 |
| 2 | CMA, CPR | 2 | 25 |
| 3 | CMA, CPR | 2 | 25 |

I would like for the NewPriceTotal to be set at the members_amountdue from the members table but I'm not sure where I made the wrong turn at.  Any help, comments or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That update is a separate statement, and has no idea about anything you did with CTEs. CTEs are like temporary, inline views, and aren't persisted. Perhaps you should dump the output to a #temp table and change your UPDATE statement to join to the #temp table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
....
CTE2 AS ( 
   SELECT members_id
   FROM members
), CTE3 AS (
   SELECT  CTE.members_id, CTE.Credentials, CTE.CredCount,  
           CTE.members_amountdue,  
           (CTE.members_amountdue + 25) as NewPriceTotal
   FROM CTE JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.members_id = CTE2.members_id
   WHERE CTE.CredCount = 2)
UPDATE CTE3
SET members_amountdue = NewPriceTotal
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion however this encounters an error"Msg 4403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update the view or function 'CTE3' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator."

Comment: @Jay this is due to the `DISTINCT` keyword being used in the top-level CTE. The `UPDATE` is propagated to the real table in the database. Using `DISTINCT` makes things hard for the engine to determine which exact row to update. What would the result be had you not used `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Thanks Giorgos - I appreciate the help.  Your suggestions were right.