# How do I run a sql update on the results of a query

Tags: sql-server

```
WITH A   -- Get a list of unique combinations of Shipmentnumber and ShipmentType
AS  (
   SELECT Distinct
          f_Shipmentnumber
     ,    f_ShipmentType
   FROM  t_shipment
)
,   B  -- Get a list of all those shipmentnumbers values that have more than one shipmentType associated
AS  (
    SELECT f_Shipmentnumber
    FROM   A
    GROUP BY
           f_Shipmentnumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
         A.f_Shipmentnumber
    ,    A.f_ShipmentType
FROM    A
    JOIN B
        ON  A.f_Shipmentnumber = B.f_Shipmentnumber
```

This is what I have and it returns beautifully however I need to set shipmentType=1 where shipmentTyp=2 for just these results.

Comment: Do you need help with [**CTE UPDATE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte) syntaxis, or changing the SQL result?

Comment: this returns duplicate shipment numbers with different shipment types. I need to update the shipment types but just for these duplicate shipment numbers only

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: How would I add columns to these results with out changing these results? I need to add the date a few other columns but when I do it changes the number of rows being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another CTE for that last select, and then just use an update statement:

```
WITH A   -- Get a list of unique combinations of Shipmentnumber and ShipmentType
AS  (
   SELECT Distinct
          f_Shipmentnumber
     ,    f_ShipmentType
   FROM  t_shipment
)
,   B  -- Get a list of all those shipmentnumbers values that have more than one shipmentType associated
AS  (
    SELECT f_Shipmentnumber
    FROM   A
    GROUP BY
           f_Shipmentnumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
), C -- This CTE will be the one for your update statement, assuming that f_shipmentnumber is a primary key
AS ( 
    SELECT 
             A.f_Shipmentnumber
        ,    A.f_ShipmentType
    FROM    A
        JOIN B
            ON  A.f_Shipmentnumber = B.f_Shipmentnumber
)
UPDATE t_shipment
SET f_ShipmentType = 1
FROM C as cte
   JOIN t_shipment s ON cte.f_shipmentnumber = s.f_shipmentnumber
WHERE cte.f_shipmenttype = 2
```

Note that the update statement simply joins the final CTE results by `f_shipmentnumber`, and the update will only update the records that are returned in that final select statement, now wrapped in a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

if you want change `1` for `2` just use a `CASE`

```
SELECT 
         CASE WHEN A.f_Shipmentnumber = 2
              THEN 1
              ELSE A.f_Shipmentnumber
         END as f_Shipmentnumber
    ,    A.f_ShipmentType
FROM    A
    JOIN B
        ON  A.f_Shipmentnumber = B.f_Shipmentnumber
```