# How does this CTE update work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have these tables:

**Items**:

```
ID (PK)
ItemName
```

**ItemsCategoryLink**:

```
ItemID (FK)
CatID
ItemOrder
```

For each `CatID` in the link table, I can set the display order of the items.
Now I want to update the `ItemOrder` based on the `Items.ItemName`

And this CTE update:

```
;WITH cteUpdate AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Items.ItemName,
        ItemsCategoryLink.ItemOrder, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Items.ItemName DESC) AS NewItemOrder
    FROM 
        Items 
    INNER JOIN
        ItemsCategoryLink ON Items.ID = ItemsCategoryLink.ItemID
    WHERE 
        ItemsCategoryLink.CatID = '{390510E6-765B-4E5D-989F-F13B259FF1D2}'
)
UPDATE cteUpdate 
SET ItemOrder = NewItemOrder
```

To my surprise this updated the underlying `ItemsCategoryLink.ItemOrder` correctly. I am not selecting any PK in the CTE.

How does this exactly worked? How did the update CTE updates the **underlying** table? Does the update CTE depend on a primary key so it knows which rows to update?

Please advice.

Comment: It has a row in the cte that contains both values right? It is essentially doing update yourtable set yourcolumn = newvalue where yourcolumn = oldvalue. I am not really sure what you are looking for as an answer here.

Comment: To add more surprise, `select` a column from `Items` table inside the `CTE`  update will fail

Comment: @Pரதீப், No. it did **not** failed.

Comment: You may want to read up on `update ... from ...`, e.g. [this](http://sqlity.net/en/2867/update-from-select/) and many other articles, blogs, ... .

Comment: @zig - My bad, it wil fail if you try to update the column from both the tables. `UPDATE cteUpdate 
SET ItemOrder = NewItemOrder,ItemName= 'fail'`

Comment: No, the CTE does not depend on any PK at all. As long as rows can be traced back to one table, they can be updated. It's up to you to make sure the results make sense: "the results of an `UPDATE` statement are undefined if the statement includes a `FROM` clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the `UPDATE` statement is not deterministic." Think of a CTE as an alternate way to write that `FROM`.

Comment: All it's doing is updating Item.ItemOrder so that they are all in sequential order based on their current order. It'll remove any gaps in the sequense and/or any dupe values... Of course it's being limited to items in  ItemsCategoryLink.CatID = '{390510E6-765B-4E5D-989F-F13B259FF1D2}'

Comment: @SeanLange, *"It is essentially doing update yourtable set yourcolumn = newvalue where yourcolumn = oldvalue"* - Are you sure about this? but even if the oldvalue is the same for all rows (e.g. 0), it will update the newvalue correctly (based on `ItemsCategoryLink.ItemID`). not randomly.

Comment: Of course it doesn't do it randomly.

Comment: `Updates you make to the CTE will be cascaded to the source table.` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update records in table from CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte)