# Is SELECT/UPDATE with CTE atomic in a T-SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select and update a single row based on search that might result in multiple rows which I in turn need to sort.

I'm using a CTE (as shown below) to combine `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. However, I'm not sure if the `UPDATE/INSERT` combo is guaranteed to be atomic.

Sample code:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        column1,
        column2,
        column3      
    FROM 
        table1
    WHERE 
        column1 = 0 
    ORDER BY 
        column2
)
UPDATE cte 
SET column1 = 1
OUTPUT inserted.*
```

Comment: Of course it is. If something as basic as updates and inserts weren't fully atomic the DBMS would be pretty much useless.

Comment: Curious why not use a merge statement? I think that would be the cleaner way to do an Update/Insert

Comment: @SeanLange:  I'm new to CTE and just want to make sure that both SELECT and UPDATE will execute as a _single_ atomic operation. Could you confirm?

Comment: What is the actual concern here? Are you afraid the update will somehow a row other than the one it selected?

Comment: @SeanLange: I'd like to select a row based on column1 value and update it without worrying that someone else changes the value between my select and update.  This is why I need select and update to be atomic.

Comment: If a cte and the query that used it wasn't it would make ctes totally useless because it would violate A in ACID.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte#comment70033423_11562724

Comment: @SeanLange - most people assume that a MERGE is atomic but it is not, and this is very much like a MERGE in that it has a SELECT and then an UPDATE.  If the SQL Docs dont say its an atomic operation and there is no evidence to show that it is, the concern is legitimate.

Comment: @StingyJack my comments are from almost 5 years ago. But you are absolutely correct that most people (including myself 5 years ago) believe it to be atomic. Aaron Bertrand has a great article on the topic. here. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ And a great solution to the problem here. https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern