# Adding a surrogate key to existing table (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table of 225 million rows. It does NOT have any primary keys. It's just a sheet of data.

I want to add a TableID, and set surrogate keys to it. I've created the `TableID bigint` column.

What's the fastest way to put in key values (1, 2,3, etc...)?

This is just horrendous as the optimizer sees it.

```
with CTE as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (ORDER BY GEOID, A_ID, Zip, latitude, longitude) as rn,
    GID,
    A_ID,
    Zip,
    latitude,
    longitude from tableA
) update Table a set a.TableID = CTE.rn 
    where a.GID = CTE.GID
    and a.A_ID = CTE.A_ID
    and a.Zip = CTE.Zip
    and a.latitude = CTE.latutude
    and a.longitude = CTE.longitude;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Most databases have an auto-increment mechanism you can use for surrogate keys. If you add a column that is an auto-increment column, It should be done quite fast, even for a large table. You didn't specify the RDBMS you are working with, and auto-increment columns are vendor specific, so I'm not going to attempt an answer.

Comment: I apologize.  I meant SQL Server.....I'll update...

Comment: `ALTER TABLE TableName ADD Id int identity(1,1)` took 2 seconds on a 100,000 records table, once I've got a million records it was much slower (I've canceled after 30 seconds). 225 million records would probably be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the database, so I'll assume PostgreSQL. Then, why not use a `sequence`?

```
create sequence my_new_table_id;

alter table tablea add column tableid bigint;

update tablea set tableid = nextval('my_new_table_id');
```

Other databases offer similar solutions, all of them pretty fast.

Comment: Although I do claim the bust of not saying which database, and it's not PostgreSQL, I have a friend who was looking for this on PostGIS.  So I'm going to plus 1 for you here for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I used this example:

[Update records in table from CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte)

to generate this:

```
;with CTE as (
     select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GEOID, A_ID, Zip, latitude, longitude) as rn,
     TableID,
     GID,
     A_ID,
     Zip,
     latitude,
     longitude from tableA
) update CTE set CTE.TableID = CTE.rn
```

took alot away from the Optimizer.  Hope it helps someone else.