# Need advice on how to do a proper select and update query I'm unsure where i went wrong

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

The Select statement works however, I can figure out why it doesn't update the price.

Just the background of the variable names whenfinalised is the date of confirmation of purchase. 
PP is the table containing a product key and the purchase finalized date.

The purpose was to update the prices based on the days from the last purchase and the second part has an extra where clause which count if the product is purchased less than 5 times in 20 days.

```
SELECT book.p#, product.price 
FROM product,book
JOIN PP
ON pp.p# = book.p#
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET PRICE = product.price * 0.97
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE ((SYSDATE-whenfinalised)>=30);

SELECT video.p# , product.price,COUNT(video.p#)
FROM video,product
JOIN pp
ON pp.p# = video.p#
UPDATE PRODUCT 
SET PRICE = product.price * 0.95
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE EXISTS((SYSDATE-whenfinalised)>=20) AND (COUNT(video.p#)< 5);
```

It tells me my UPDATE PRODUCT , SQL command is not properly ended.

Comment: Start by not cramming your queries together to make it difficult to read and understand. Next, SYSDATE is not tsql - perhaps oracle or mysql. Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will quite generic, because there is no testing data. In the second `UPDATE` you have `COUNT` which means that you need `GROUP BY` clause. Unfortunately, `UPDATE` doesn't support `GROUP BY`. You can achieve that by combining [`CTE` and `UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte). Additionally, you mixed up the syntax. Please look at the link that I posted. You will find how to write your query.