# Add sequence number to existing table for each column with group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have following data:

```
ID      Code      value
580     SSSACCT   111
580     SSSACCT   112
580     TIX       10
580     TIX       30
35      SSSACCT   345
35      SSSACCT   344
35      SSSACCT   433
35      SSSACCT   221
```

And I want to update the data like below by replacing 'SSSACCT' with 'SSSAC' and adding sequence number to the end for each ID and same thing for the Code 'TIX':

```
ID      Code    Value
580     SSSAC1  111
580     SSSAC2  112
580     TIX1    10
580     TIX2    30
35      SSSAC1  345
35      SSSAC2  344
35      SSSAC3  433
35      SSSAC4  221
```

So far I tried to use T-SQL (Variables) to add the number to end (Not sure if that is correct) but I am not sure how to group this based on ID.
Any help would be appreciated.

The code I wrote so far:

```
DECLARE @myVar int
SET @myVar = 0
UPDATE
  table
SET
  @myvar = ID = @myVar + 1
Group by ID,Code   --I know we cannot use group by in update but we may able to use in sub query
```

Comment: use row_number() ...

Comment: Thank you @MitchWheat, Can I use group by option in row_number()? I may able to add number to end but how to group by them based on other colomns?

Comment: How do you determine the order of the rows? A table is a bag of rows with no inherent order.

Comment: @HABO I am not sure how to make sure about this, But I may add the order by clause after grouping them.

Comment: Let me ask again in a different way: Why does `35`/`SSSAC`/`344` get numbered _after_ `35`/`SSSAC`/`345`? There isn't a column or combination of columns that provides the order that you seem to assume. No serial number or date/time that makes it easy to determine which row is "next". Do you just want numbers assigned to make the `Code` values different with an `Id`, but don't care how the numbers are assigned?

Comment: @HABO Exactly as you said, I don't care about the sequence, as long as it make it unique, it will work. I do not need to use date stamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number as suggested by Mitch Wheat to figure out the values

here is some sample code that breaks it down

You can then use the result to update your original table

```
;with mycte as (
select 

580 as ID ,   'SSSACCT' as code,   111 as value
union all select
580,     'SSSACCT',   112
union all select
580 ,    'TIX',    10
union all select
580 ,    'TIX' ,      30
union all select
35 ,     'SSSACCT',   345
union all select
35 ,     'SSSACCT',   344
union all select
35 ,     'SSSACCT' ,  433
union all select
35 ,     'SSSACCT',   221
)
, mycte2 as (
Select mycte.* , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by code, ID order by ID) as row_num
from mycte

)

Select 
mycte2.*
, concat(replace(code,'CT',''),row_num) as new_code
from mycte2
```

Comment: Thank you Harry for your time and response, I am afraid I may not able to use cte since I have a table that has 12000 data inside. Is there anyway to just select it from that table?

Comment: 12000 records is a rather small table. have you tried running this against your data

Comment: @Christiano there is no row limit when it comes to a CTE?

Comment: I am going to try this now and will let you know. So I am going to not use the first cte

Comment: The first CTE is just to build the sample data for completeness ... use the mycte2 onward.. of course, the from will be your table name

Comment: dear @Harry, Can I insert the cte2 into a table? I tried to do this but I could not do it: "with mycte2 as (
Select * , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by usa_code, us_no order by us_no) as row_num into table22
from table1
)"

Comment: I though you want to update the original data.. if you want to inset it somewhere.. you can create a temp table to insert it.. but you should be able to update your original table with the derived cte.

Comment: @Harry, Yes I wanted to update it, but how we can update the table with mycte2?

Comment: @Harry what I undrestand, we could have the data as I described with cte and we select that data as well. But the question I have now is how can I use this cte in order to update my table?

Comment: rather than reinvent the wheel for the update part  - refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte - always ensure you have backed up your data before you attempt an update.. do it on a test system first to ensure the results are as desired... ALWAYS!