# Cannot UPDATE a CTE ( but SELECT works)?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) and [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562724) on this forum, it should be trivial to `UPDATE` a CTE in a `WITH` query ... but I cannot succeed  !

What am I doing wrong for example here in this simple example ?

```
WITH val AS (VALUES (1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33))
UPDATE val SET column1=column1*2 ;
```

this throws me an error

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "val" does not exist
> LINE 3: UPDATE val SET column1=column1*2 ;
>                ^
> ```

whereas this example with `SELECT` works:

```
WITH val AS (VALUES (1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33))
SELECT 2*column1 as new, column2 FROM val;
```

> ```
>  new | column2 
> -----+---------
>    2 |      11
>    4 |      22
>    6 |      33
> (3 rows)
> ```

Comment: You can only update real tables, not CTEs

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks but what about the example in the link I gave where a CTE is clearly updated ? Am I wrong ? What about official docs ?

Comment: Well, that's for SQL Server, not for Postgres