# Update data in temporary table with new records found with joins on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, temp-tables

I have data in a temporary table and I need to update this with the new data found with other tables using joins. How can I change the second select to an update statement?
Can you please suggest how to do this?
Thank you

```
SELECT 
    sc.str_psn, sc.str_esn, sc.id_smartcard, sc.id_customer, st.str_statusdesc,
    pax.str_title
INTO #temp 
FROM Smartrack.dbo.Smartcard sc
INNER JOIN Smartrack.dbo.Customer pax on sc.id_customer = pax.id_customer
INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.StatusType st ON sc.int1_cardstatus = st.int1_statustype


SELECT  
     t.str_psn , t.str_esn, t.id_smartcard, t.id_customer, t.str_statusdesc,
     t.str_title, subpax.datAdded, tok.str_token_desc, subpax.ultTokenType
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.id_Customer, u.id_TravelToken, u.ultTokenType, u.datAdded, u.ultTokenExpiry 
    FROM SmarTrack.dbo.Customer p
    INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.Smartcard s ON p.id_customer = s.id_customer
    INNER JOIN SmartrackInterface.dbo.vwUltimateCardDetails u ON s.id_smartcard = u.id_smartcard
    WHERE s.id_replacement_smartcard IS NULL                    
) subpax ON t.id_customer = subpax.id_CUstomer 
INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.TravelToken tt ON subpax.id_TravelToken = tt.id_traveltoken
INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.TokenType tok on subpax.ultTokenType = tok.int2_tokentype
```

Comment: What have you tried? The documentation on the update statement provides plenty of examples... where did you get stuck?

Comment: `How can I change the second select to an update statement`. Change the `SELECT` to `UPDATE t` follow by `SET` and specify the list of columns in `#temp` that you want to update. Something like `UPDATE t SET somecol = subpax.somecol from #temp t inner join . . . . `

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this: [Update records in table from CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562536/update-records-in-table-from-cte)

Your can try the following method

```
with cte as(
SELECT  
     t.str_psn , t.str_esn, t.id_smartcard, t.id_customer, t.str_statusdesc,
     t.str_title, subpax.datAdded, tok.str_token_desc, subpax.ultTokenType
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.id_Customer, u.id_TravelToken, u.ultTokenType, u.datAdded, u.ultTokenExpiry 
    FROM SmarTrack.dbo.Customer p
    INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.Smartcard s ON p.id_customer = s.id_customer
    INNER JOIN SmartrackInterface.dbo.vwUltimateCardDetails u ON s.id_smartcard = u.id_smartcard
    WHERE s.id_replacement_smartcard IS NULL                    
) subpax ON t.id_customer = subpax.id_CUstomer 
INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.TravelToken tt ON subpax.id_TravelToken = tt.id_traveltoken
INNER JOIN SmarTrack.dbo.TokenType tok on subpax.ultTokenType = tok.int2_tokentype
)

Update #temp 
Set #temp.id_customer in (Select distinct id_customer From cte)
```