# Is being able to refer to a CTE in a FROM-less UPDATE clause undocumented behaviour?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, dml

The syntax for the first part of `UPDATE` [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as follows

```sql
UPDATE   
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]   
    { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited   
         [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]  
      }  
      | @table_variable      
    }
```

and `<object>` is defined as

```sql
<object> ::=  
{   
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name .   
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] .   
    | schema_name .  
    ]  
    table_or_view_name}
```

Furthermore,

> table_or_view_name
>
> Is the name of the table or view from which the rows are to be updated. The view referenced by table_or_view_name must be updatable and reference exactly one base table in the FROM clause of the view. For more information about updatable views, see CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL).

To the best of my knowledge, none of the above refer to CTEs. And yet, putting a reference to a CTE immediately after `UPDATE` is totally valid. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562724/10319707) shows this valid example

```sql
;WITH T AS
(   SELECT  InvoiceNumber, 
            DocTotal, 
            SUM(Sale + VAT) OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceNumber) AS NewDocTotal
    FROM    PEDI_InvoiceDetail
)
UPDATE  T
SET     DocTotal = NewDocTotal
```

Note that there is nothing between `UPDATE` and the reference to the CTE, not even a `FROM`.

Have I missed something in the documentation, or is being able to put a CTE immediately after `UPDATE` undocumented behaviour?

Note that I am not talking about the `FROM` clause in an update. I'm talking about `UPDATE FOO` where `FOO` is a CTE. There are examples of using CTEs in the documentation, but all of them use the `FROM` clause.

Comment: `CTE immediately after UPDATE`? Did you mean ***before***?

Comment: @MatBailie No. See my final code block. The CTE `T` is referred to immediately after the `UPDATE`. There is nothing in between, not even a `FROM`. Being able to define a CTE by putting it before `UPDATE` is clearly documented.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confused. The `T` is a reference, not the CTE itself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-over 16 : **CTE_query_definition**
Specifies a SELECT statement whose result set populates the common table expression. The SELECT statement for ***CTE_query_definition must meet the same requirements as for creating a view***, except a CTE can't define another CTE. For more information, see the Remarks section and CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL).

Comment: @MatBailie I've updated to make it a bit clearer. Regardless, is being able to refer to a reference documented?

Comment: @MatBailie Two things have the same requirements does not make them the same.

Comment: References to CTEs are evaluated with macro like substitution. Their definition is substituted in to the query that references it. It ***is*** an inline view.

Comment: I'm curious, are you creating a SQL Server fork? Or what's with these basic questions? It doesn't seem to be documented explicitly, but yes, your can refer to CTE in most places where a table name can be referred to

Comment: It's usage like this is even described in the very link you used in you question

Comment: FROM <table_source>
Specifies that a table, view, or derived table source is used to provide the criteria for the update operation. For more information, see FROM (Transact-SQL).

Comment: The `UPDATE` documentation you link has `WITH <common_table_expression>`  and that is defined as "Specifies the temporary named result set or view" - so seems implied that you can use  it as `table_or_view_name`

Comment: @siggemannen I was trying to find where the documentation says that you can't modify two different tables in the `SET` clause and ended up noticing things like this while I was studying it deeply. I've still yet to find that part of `SET`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it misrepresents the online help page it references. (Which covers the Op's scenario completely.)

Comment: @MartinSmith Huh. I think you might have the full answer. MatBailie has been very convincing, but I think you've found exactly where the documentation has what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, but let's say you won't find X in documentation. How does it change the situation for you, if when you do X you get an error?

Comment: @siggemannen Because if my understanding doesn't match the documentation, then I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not totally convinced. "*The view referenced by table_or_view_name must be updatable and reference exactly one base table in the FROM clause of the view.*" isn't true of CTEs. You're definitely allowed to update a CTE that references more than one base table. The truth is that you're now allowed to update more than once base table at once, but what I've said is true does not match the part of the documentation that I've quoted.

Comment: You can add that to their github so they can clarify the docs if something is wrong / unclear. Base table != table probably though.

Comment: They literally put the from clause within brackets in the documentation. The entire purpose of those brackets are to tell you it's optional. They aren't there because Microsoft thought it would make it pretty

Comment: @GlockByte There are countless situations that would make the `FROM` clause optional. Are you arguing that saying that the `FROM` clause is optional means that this specific usage of CTEs is documented?

Comment: CTE usage is documented, FROM clause is documented, and UPDATE statement is documented. You would need to read between all three documentations to know that it's redundant to reference a source table when the source table is the object. You will notice the UPDATE documentation puts the FROM clause in brackets. This isn't specific to CTE's, it applies to the UPDATE statement itself. Therefor this is covered in the documentation. If you want them to give examples for every scenario; That's simply unrealistic as we would never be able to read all of that

Answer (score 2):

Please read the Microsoft's [syntax conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to better understand how to translate their documentation:

> [ ] (brackets)    Optional syntax item.

[UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  

[ WITH <common_table_expression> [...n] ]  <--Optional per Microsoft
UPDATE   
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]   
    { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited   
         [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]  
      }  
      | @table_variable      
    }  
    SET  
        { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }  
          | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression  
                                | field_name = expression }  
                                | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] )  
                              }  
          }  
          | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }  
          | @variable = expression  
          | @variable = column = expression  
          | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
          | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
          | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
        } [ ,...n ]   
  
    [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]  
    [ FROM{ <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] <--Optional per Microsoft
    [ WHERE { <search_condition>   
            | { [ CURRENT OF   
                  { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name }   
                      | cursor_variable_name   
                  }   
                ]  
              }  
            }   
    ]   
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]  
[ ; ]  
  
<object> ::=  
{   
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name .   
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] .   
    | schema_name .  
    ]  
    table_or_view_name}  <--CTE is a result set as per the documentation for CTEs
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the documentation is incomplete on this.  Where it says:

```
<object> ::=  
{   
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name .   
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] .   
    | schema_name .  
    ]  
    table_or_view_name}
```

It *should* say something like:

```
<object> ::=  
{   
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name .   
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] .   
    | schema_name .  
    ]  
    writeable_table_expression}
```

This oversight in the doc has been around at least as long as
CTEs have been in SQL Server, and this is not the only place that has this problem.

Comment: Do you have some more evidence or examples to back this up? If you're right, then I would presume that there would be many pull requests or issues raised on GitHub.

Comment: @J.Mini Not sure what you're looking for here.  AFAIK, we do not have access to the MS internal task management logs, if you do, then I'd encourage you to put in your own pull request.  You can check the DOC back to 2016 at the MS site, it's the same on this issue, and I noticed this particular matter at least as far back as 2010.  As for examples, you can find examples of people using CTEs in UPDATEs at least as far back.

Comment: I imagine most practitioners  haven't pursued this minor doc omission because they understood that you can generally use a CTE anywhere you could use a View with the same content (as long as the leading `WITH ...` is supported).

Comment: This is the assumption that everything must be in the displayed code within the documentation and not outside in a simple paragraph of the documentation. CTE documentation says it must be followed by a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statement and that the statement MUST reference the CTE. So I fail to see the issue. The documentation is there, it's not just all shoved into one code snippet

Answer (score -2):

perform the update in the destination table, table t is a subquery table

```
WITH T AS
(   SELECT  InvoiceNumber, 
            SUM(Sale + VAT) OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceNumber) AS NewDocTotal
    FROM    PEDI_InvoiceDetail
)
UPDATE  PEDI_InvoiceDetail 
SET     DocTotal = NewDocTotal
FROM            PEDI_InvoiceDetail INNER JOIN
                         T ON PEDI_InvoiceDetail.InvoiceNumber = T.InvoiceNumber
```