# Delete from CTE with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, dml

I'm  trying to implement a FIFO queue using a sql table.

I have the following SQL (modified for posting), the join and param usage are important to the way this process works.

```
With cte as (
   select top(1) q.* from queue q with (readpast)
   inner join MyTable a on q.id = a.myTableID AND myTable.procID = @myParam
   order by q.Data asc
)
delete from cte
    output
      deleted.ID,
      deleted.col1
```

running this statement returns an error 'View or function 'cte' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.'

I understand why the error is thrown, what I can't figure out is how to fix it. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `exists()` instead of the inner join to `MyTable` in the CTE.

```
with cte as 
(
  select top(1) q.id,
                q.col1
  from queue q with (readpast)
  where exists(
              select *
              from  MyTable a 
              where  q.id = a.myTableID AND 
                     a.procID = @myParam
              )
  order by q.Data asc
)
delete from cte
output deleted.ID, deleted.col1;
```

Comment: What's nice about this approach over the examples provided by Kieninger is that it provides a consistent approach for building up DELETE commands where you can first test the results of the SELECT to see what rows the DELETE from cte is going to affect.

Answer (score 13):

Something like this?

```
With cte as (
   select top(1) q.* from queue q with (readpast)
   inner join MyTable a on q.id = a.myTableID AND myTable.procID = @myParam
   order by q.Data asc
)
delete from queue
Where ID in (Select Id from cte)
```

Comment: It's definitely possible to delete from a CTE, sql server infers the underlying table from the select statement. The problem I have is I'm joining on another table, so the table to delete from is now ambiguous.

I'll do some testing around your answer, concurrency is going to be an issue here, so I'm worried about locking around the IN statement.

Answer (score 3):

The use of a CTE feels forced here. You can simply:

```
 DELETE FROM [queue]
  WHERE id IN ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 
           q.id 
      FROM [queue] q WITH (READPAST)
           INNER JOIN 
           MyTable a ON q.id = a.myTableID 
                    AND myTable.procID = @myParam
    ORDER BY q.Data ASC)
```

If you want to use a CTE I like @sarin's answer, but using an EXIST instead:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 
         q.id 
    FROM [queue] q WITH (READPAST)
         INNER JOIN 
         MyTable a ON q.id = a.myTableID 
                  AND myTable.procID = @myParam
   ORDER BY q.Data ASC
)
DELETE [queue] 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE cte.id = [queue].id)
```