# How can I DELETE from a CTE in which a JOIN exists?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I'm trying to implement a basic queue using tables, in SQL Server. I have "tasks" that I want to add to my "queue". Here is my `Task` table, followed by my `TaskQueue` table ...

```
CREATE TABLE Task (
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  JobId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Job (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  Payload NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  PayloadType NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  DateCreated DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE TaskQueue (
  TaskId INT UNIQUE NOT NULL REFERENCES Task (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  DateCreated DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

As you can see, the queue itself is nothing but a table, as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616125556/http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) by Remus Rusanu.

I'm not concerned with order of items, so the enqueue procedure is just as Remus recommends. Below is my dequeue procedure ...

```
CREATE TYPE DequeueTaskPayloadType AS TABLE (
  PayloadType NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE DequeueTask
  @payloadTypes DequeueTaskPayloadType READONLY
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  WITH NextTask AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 q.*
    FROM TaskQueue AS q WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    JOIN Task AS t ON t.Id = q.TaskId AND t.PayloadType IN (
      SELECT PayloadType
      FROM @payloadTypes))
  DELETE FROM NextTask
  OUTPUT deleted.*;
```

My dequeue method differs from Remus' in that I need to include a `JOIN` so that I can dequeue records that have an appropriate filter - the filter can be seen in my query, but basically the `Task` has a `PayloadType` and I want the stored procedure to require an argument through which I can dequeue tasks with a specific payload type.

My problem is that when I execute my `DequeueTask` stored procedure, I get the following error ...

> View or function 'NextTask' is not updatable because the modification
>   affects multiple base tables.

I understand that my `NextTask` CTE is basically a view here but I do not understand why this affects multiple base tables. I do think it's obvious that it has to do with me using a `JOIN`, but I guess my question is ...

How can I `DELETE` from a CTE in which a `JOIN` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN won't work in CTE/DELETE, try to restructure CTE query to use WHERE EXISTS () instead of JOIN like here:

http://stevestedman.com/2015/06/deleting-from-a-cte-with-an-exists-statement/

[Delete from CTE with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761972/delete-from-cte-with-join)